# Shopping Cart, function to show the total. [JS]

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I am so frustrated with this code, I hope you can help me a bit.

As you can see I am trying to set up this code to an ecommerce project, there is a computer which cost $600 and then there are some add-ons with additional extra charge. In the 'function computer()' I verify the checks, but I want to create a function that shows up the total of the purchase, the main product which is the computer plus the add-ons.

What can I do with JS to set up a value to each add-on?

If you see some weird code is because I am using bootstrap. I am just a beginner.

I have this HTML code

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="iMac" value="iMacPC">
  <h3>Add ons</h3>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="iMac" id="ram" value="Ram"> 16 GB RAM (+$175)
    <input type="checkbox" name="iMac" id="harddrive" value="Harddrive"> 1 TB HD (+200)</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="iMac" id="guaranteed" value="Guaranteed"> Extended Guarantee (+$150)</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="iMac" id="processor" value="Processor"> Core i7-4700HQ 2.4 GHz (+$125)</p>
  <br>
  <p><input type="button" id="buttonMac" onclick="computer();" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value='Order Now &raquo;'></p>
  <p><input class="alert alert-info" type="text" id="order1" size="50" style="display: none;"></p>
</form>
```

which is according to this JS function to determine the checks.

```
function computer(){
  var iMac = document.forms[1].iMac,
      txt = "",
      i;

  if (iMac.checked === null) {
    return false;
  }

  document.getElementById("order1").value = "Please select at least one Item";
  document.getElementById("order1").style.color = "#E34234";

  for (i=0; i<iMac.length; i++){
    if (iMac[i].checked){
      txt = txt + iMac[i].value + " ";
      document.getElementById("order1").value = "Order: " + txt;
      document.getElementById("order1").style.color = "#2980b9";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems your problem is here `if(iMac.checked === null)`. Don't check strict `null`, try `if (!iMac.checked)`

Comment: @elclanrs great, I will do it right now but your comment does not answer my question. I need to set up a value ($) to each checkbox. I mean, if the computer cost 600 $ and the customer choose the computer and the RAM add on which cost 175 $, the function returns the total of the purchase, so 775 $ in that case.

Comment: You see the problem is in txt = txt + iMac[i].value + " ";
which is adding the values as string rather than Integer. Force one to be integer and add the string (" ") later to calculate all the values from the checkboxes. Like txt+=parseInt(iMac[i].value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Method 1 - use the `value` attribute to hold the cost

By storing the price in the `value` attribute you can easily convert it into an integer and add it to a total:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="iMac" id="iMacPC" value="600"> iMacPC </input>
<h3>Add ons</h3>
<input type="checkbox" name="iMac" id="Ram" value="175"> 16 GB RAM (+$175) </input>
<input type="checkbox" name="iMac" id="Harddrive" value="200"> 1 TB HD (+200) </input>
<input type="checkbox" name="iMac" id="Guaranteed" value="150"> Extended Guarantee (+$150) </input>
<input type="checkbox" name="iMac" id="Processor" value="125"> Core i7-4700HQ 2.4 GHz (+$125) </input>
```

**JavaScript**

```
parseInt(iMac[i].value); // the price
```

You can then use the `id` attribute to save the name of the item:

```
iMac[i].id; // the item name
```

With this idea you can simply loop through all checked inputs:

```
var iMac = document.orderForm.iMac; // array of inputs
var totalOrder = "";                // list all checked ids
var totalCost = 0;                  // add values to calculate cost

for (var i = 0; i < iMac.length; i++){
    if (iMac[i].checked) {
        totalOrder += iMac[i].id + " ";       // add ids separated by spaces
        totalCost += parseInt(iMac[i].value); // add value attributes, assuming they are integers
    }
}
```

### [Here is a Fiddle for a full working example](http://jsfiddle.net/TrevinAvery/cdvb6/)

## Method 2 - use the `id` attribute to decide the price

You can decide the price by using a `switch` statement on the `id`s of the `input`s:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="iMac" id="iMacPC" value="iMacPC"> iMacPC </input>
<h3>Add ons</h3>
<input type="checkbox" name="iMac" id="ram" value="Ram"> 16 GB RAM (+$175) </input>
<input type="checkbox" name="iMac" id="harddrive" value="Harddrive"> 1 TB HD (+200) </input>
<input type="checkbox" name="iMac" id="guaranteed" value="Guaranteed"> Extended Guarantee (+$150) </input>
<input type="checkbox" name="iMac" id="processor" value="Processor"> Core i7-4700HQ 2.4 GHz (+$125) </input>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var iMac = document.orderForm.iMac; // array of inputs
var totalOrder = "";                // list all checked item names from value
var totalCost = 0;                  // add values to calculate cost

for (var i = 0; i < iMac.length; i++){
    if (iMac[i].checked) {
        totalOrder += iMac[i].value + " "; // add values separated by spaces for list of item names
        totalCost += getPrice(iMac[i].id); // add value attributes, assuming they are integers
    }
}

function getPrice(id) {
    switch (id) {
        case "iMacPC":
            return 600;
        case "ram":
            return 175;
        case "harddrive":
            return 200;
        case "guaranteed":
            return 150;
        case "processor":
            return 125;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Or you can use a 2d array and a `for` loop:

```
function getPrice(id) {
    var prices = [
        ["iMacPC", 600],
        ["ram", 175],
        ["harddrive", 200],
        ["guaranteed", 200],
        ["processor", 125]
    ];

    for(var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
        if (id === prices[i][0]) {
            return prices[i][1];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### [Here is a Fiddle for using a `switch` statement](http://jsfiddle.net/TrevinAvery/cdvb6/4/)

### [And here is a Fiddle for using a 2d array and a `for` loop](http://jsfiddle.net/TrevinAvery/cdvb6/5/)

## Related Tips

### Tip 1 - use the `action` attribute on the `form`

Instead of using:

```
<form>
  <input type="button" onclick="computer();">Button</input>
</form>
```

You should use:

```
<form action="javascript:computer()">
  <input type="submit">Button</input>
</form>
```

When the user presses 'enter' while a form is in focus, the default behaviour is to submit the form by performing the action. By using the `action` attribute and the `submit` type input, you will catch the 'enter' key if it is pressed. This will give the user an expected result and avoid accidentally reloading the page (which can happen in some situations).

### Tip 2 - always use closing tags

It is a good idea to ALWAYS close your tags. If a tag is not properly closed it may render incorrectly or the browser may ignore/delete it.

This line:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="iMac" value="iMacPC">
```

Would be better as:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="iMac" value="iMacPC"></input>
```

### Tip 3 - DO NOT use JavaScript to calculate the final price

If you plan on actually charging users, make sure that you generate the bill on the server side. If you use the price from the JavaScript (client side), the user can easily change this number to whatever he/she wants, and could possibly rob you of your payment.